# how to Pass array from view to controller in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I make a form in blade.php, Here I can select multiple checkbox, and I want to pass selected input’s value to controller in a array.But I failed, I can not send the data.
Here is code from view. The selected input’s value can be 1,2 etc;

```
<form method="post" action="{{action('votesubmitController@votesubmit')}}" class="form">

<input type="hidden"  name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

@foreach($candidate_list[$post_list->id] as $candidate_list[$post_list->id])

<li>
  <input type="checkbox"  name= "selected[]"  value= {{ 
$candidate_list[$post_list->id]->id }}>
  <label>
  <!-- some code here -->
  </label>
</li>

@endforeach
<button type="submit" id="login-button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here is route-

```
Route::post('/votesubmit','votesubmitController@votesubmit');
```

If I write return $input in controller I find –

```
{"_token":"TQIUxVz0LjzM84Z7TaUPk3Y7BLZPjmXUyhXhlQfp","selected":
  ["1","2"]}
```

That’s I need. I do not know how to get selected value. When I get specific route error exception happens . and says "Undefined variable: selected".
Here is my Controller’s code-

```
class votesubmitController extends Controller
{
public function votesubmit()
{
  $input = Input::all();
 // return $input;     
  foreach ($selected as $selected) {
     echo $selected;
  }
}
}
```

Comment: `$selected = $input['selected'];` add this in your controller.

Comment: Thanks , It works...

Comment: @linktoahref . please place it in answers. And Alimur, accept that so this question can be displayed as solved

Answer (score 2):

```
// You can try this
class votesubmitController extends Controller
{
 public function votesubmit()
 {
  //$input = Input::all();
  //$selected = $input['selected'];
  $selected = Input::get('selected');   
   foreach ($selected as $selected) 
   {
    echo $selected;
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use
`$selected = $input['selected']`
Or 
pass it using Ajax.